# TypeError: $jscomp$generator$this.send is not a function

Tags: clojurescript, shadow-cljs

I'm trying to use @walletconnect/web3-provider package from npm in ClojureScript, and when I call a function I get an error: **TypeError: $jscomp$generator$this.send is not a function**

Here is JavaScript code which is used, the problem is in 4th line: `return this.send(payload);`:

```js
      class WalletConnectProvider extends ProviderEngine {
        request(payload) {
            return tslib_1.__awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
                return this.send(payload);
            });
        }
        send(payload, callback) {
            return tslib_1.__awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
                if (typeof payload === "string") {
                    const method = payload;
                    let params = callback;
                    if (method === "personal_sign") {
                        params = utils_1.parsePersonalSign(params);
                    }
                    return this.sendAsyncPromise(method, params);
                }
                payload = Object.assign({ id: utils_1.payloadId(), jsonrpc: "2.0" }, payload);
                if (payload.method === "personal_sign") {
                    payload.params = utils_1.parsePersonalSign(payload.params);
                }
                if (callback) {
                    this.sendAsync(payload, callback);
                    return;
                }
                return this.sendAsyncPromise(payload.method, payload.params);
            });
        }
```

Here is ClojureScript code which causes error described above when I call `(.getAccounts (.-eth web3))`

```
(ns woodenstaking-ui.components.connect-btn
  (:require [re-frame.core :as rf]
            ["web3" :as web3-js]
            ["web3modal" :default web3-modal]
            ["@walletconnect/web3-provider" :default wallet-connect-provider]
            ["fortmatic" :as fortmatic]
            [cljs.core.async :refer [go]]
            [cljs.core.async.interop :refer-macros [<p!]]

(def web3modal
 (new web3-modal #js {:cacheProvider false,
                      :providerOptions #js
                        {:walletconnect #js
                           {:package wallet-connect-provider,
                            :options #js {:infuraId infura-id}}
                         :fortmatic #js
                           {:package fortmatic
                            :options #js {:key fortmatic-key}}}}))

(defn open-modal
  []
  (go
      (let [provider (<p! (.connect web3modal))
            web3 (new web3-js provider)
            account (<p! (.getAccounts (.-eth web3)))])))
```

This code works with MetaMask and Fortmatic web3 providers and fails with WalletConnect only. The same error I get with WalletConnect when I call any smart contract method.